# Is it possible to know the country from which a particular tweet originated?

Tags: twitter

I am working on a problem that requires me to know the country from which the tweet originated. I do not need a smaller granularity. Just the country would do. I already have the tweets with me. Is it possible to get this information from the twitter API?

The Twitter API mentions:

> Places: When present, indicates that the tweet is associated (but not necessarily originating from) a Place .
>
> Coordinates: Represents the geographic location of this Tweet as reported by the user or client application. The inner coordinates array is formatted as geoJSON (longitude first, then latitude).

Some searching shows that Places might not be the best way to go about doing this. Should I use Coordinates instead? Are they accurate? Is there a "catch" to using it?

Comment: Do the Tweet JSON objects have any kind of place or coordinate data in them? if not, there is no way to derive this.

Comment: Some of them do. But through a rough visual inspection, I can see that most of them are set to "null". Is it because these tweets were not geo-tagged?

Comment: Yes that would be the reason

Answer (score 1):

I used the **locations** parameter to obtain tweets from a bounding box. This returns both normal and geotagged tweets.

Note that the stream returns tweets if the coordinates field is populated or if coordinates are empty but place is populated. If the coordinates field is not null, it represents the exact location on the Earth's surface from where the tweet originated (geotagged tweet). If coordinates field is null, but the place field is shown, it will show coordinates of a bounding box/polygon representative of the place tagged by the user in that normal tweet (ranging from a museum to a city/country). Twitter is also able to retrieve some location information (albeit with low granularity, say city level) from IP addresses. Details can be found in https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters.

```
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(locations = [144.9385,-37.8246,144.9761,-37.7955])
```

Edit: When you have a set of tweets pulled in a .txt file, using the Streaming API, you could employ the following code. I have made use of a Python package named Tweet Parser.

```
import pandas as pd
from tweet_parser.tweet import Tweet
from tweet_parser.tweet_parser_errors import NotATweetError
import fileinput
import json

#remove all blank lines
with open('test.txt') as infile, open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.strip(): continue  # skip the empty line
        outfile.write(line)  # non-empty line. Write it to output

df  = pd.DataFrame(columns=['DateTime','user_id','country','tweet'])
for line in fileinput.FileInput("test.json"):
    try:
        tweet_dict = json.loads(line)
        tweet = Tweet(tweet_dict)
    except (json.JSONDecodeError,NotATweetError):
        pass
    df= df.append({'DateTime':tweet.created_at_datetime,'user_id':tweet.user_id,'country':tweet_dict['place']['country'],'tweet':tweet.text},ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I was looking for. I already have the tweets with me. Out of those tweets, I need to filter out the ones that originated from a particular country. Do you think you could share some info reg. that if you could?

Comment: Sorry, I failed to address that. I am editing my answer based on a set of tweets that I retrieved. Hope that suffices.